# while working with selenium in python some error showed up

Tags: python, selenium

The problem was Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

> {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="user_name"]"}

and my code is this

```
import openpyxl as xl
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe')
wb = xl.load_workbook('Sample.xlsx')
sheet_1 = wb["Sheet1"]
cell1 = sheet_1.cell(2, 2)
cell2 = sheet_1.cell(2, 3)
driver.get('https://services.gst.gov.in/services/login')

name = driver.find_element_by_name('user_name')
name.send_keys(cell_1)

mail = driver.find_element_by_name('user_pass')
mail.send_keys(cell_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

try it out with `ExplicitWait`  :

```
driver.get("https://services.gst.gov.in/services/login")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'username'))).send_keys("some user name")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'user_pass'))).send_keys("some password")
```

**Imports**  :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```